# Limit of polynomial function with Euleur's number

Tags: limits

Good evening to everyone! Can you help me with this limit. I don't know how to solve it even though I tried l'Hospital and other techniques. It's way too complicated.
$$
\lim _{x\to -\infty }\left(\frac{\left(e^{2x}+\sin \left(x\right)e^x+e^{\frac{x}{2}}\right)}{\arctan \left(x\right)e^{\frac{x}{2}}+\cos \left(x\right)e^x}\right)
$$
Thanks a lot.

*Edit:*
What I've triyed:
1. L'Hospital rule:
$$
\lim _{x\to -\infty }\left(\frac{\left(e^{2x}+\sin \left(x\right)e^x+e^{\frac{x}{2}}\right)}{\arctan \left(x\right)e^{\frac{x}{2}}+\cos \left(x\right)e^x}\right)= \\
\lim _{x\to -\infty } \frac {\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{2x}+\sin \left(x\right)e^x+e^{\frac{x}{2}}\right)} { \frac{d}{dx}\left(\arctan \left(x\right)e^{\frac{x}{2}}\:+\cos \left(x\right)e^x\right) } = \lim _{x\to -\infty } \frac { e^{2x}2+\cos \left(x\right)e^x+e^x\sin \left(x\right)+\left(e^{\frac{x}{2}}\right)\:\frac{1}{2}}{ \frac{e^{\frac{x}{2}}}{x^2+1}+\:\arctan \left(x\right)e^{\frac{x}{2}}\:\frac{1}{2}\:+\cos \left(x\right)e^x-e^x\sin \left(x\right)}
$$

But unfortunately the equation became even more complicated.

2. By factoring out $ e^x $ :
   $$
   \lim _{x\to -\infty }\left(\frac{\left(e^{2x}+\sin \left(x\right)e^x+e^{\frac{x}{2}}\right)}{\arctan \left(x\right)e^{\frac{x}{2}}+\cos \left(x\right)e^x}\right) = \lim _{x\to -\infty }
   \frac { e^x\left(e^x+\sin \left(x\right)+e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\right) } {e^x\left(\arctan \left(x\right)e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\:+\cos \left(x\right)\right)}
   $$

I simplified $ e^x $ but even like this I would have $ \frac{\infty }{\infty } $
So I didn't know how to solve it.

Comment: Did you try to cancel out $e^{x/2}$? What happened then?

Comment: What do you mean by canceling out? How can I do that?

Comment: Factor out $e^{x/2}$ from both numerator and denominator, and see what remains. (See the answers below for details.)

Comment: Thanks.... it's because I'm not native so I'm not used to the English math terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a high-level: you only care about one term in the numerator, and one in the denominator. The other ones are negligible. So the question is: *what term decays the slowest, when $x\to-\infty$?*

$$\begin{align}
\frac{e^{2x}+\sin \left(x\right)e^x+e^{\frac{x}{2}}}{\arctan \left(x\right)e^{\frac{x}{2}}+\cos \left(x\right)e^x}
&=
\frac{e^{\frac{x}{2}}}{e^{\frac{x}{2}}}\frac{1+\sin \left(x\right)e^{\frac{1}{2}x}+e^{\frac{3}{2}x}}{\arctan \left(x\right)+\cos \left(x\right)e^{\frac{1}{2}x}}
=
\frac{1+\sin \left(x\right)e^{\frac{1}{2}x}+e^{\frac{3}{2}x}}{\arctan \left(x\right)+\cos \left(x\right)e^{\frac{1}{2}x}}\\
&=
\frac{1+o(1)}{\arctan \left(x\right)+o(1)}
\end{align}$$
when $x\to-\infty$. Now, recall that $\arctan x \xrightarrow[x\to-\infty]{}-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to conclude.

Comment: why sin(x)e^x/2 + e^3x/2 = o(1)?

Comment: Because $e^{\frac{x}{2}} \xrightarrow[x\to-\infty]{} 0$ and $e^{\frac{3}{2}x} \xrightarrow[x\to-\infty]{} 0$.

Comment: You're welcome. (Also, to whoever downvoted both answers: why? Is there a reason?)

Comment: One more question: the final result stays like this or it can be simplified to a numerical value? Like pi/2 for example. Thanks again.

Comment: @T4yl0r Read the very last part. The answer will be $\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{1}{\arctan x} = \dots$

Comment: Oh! That;s what I didn't understand whether o(1) will disappear or not from the equation. Thanks!

Comment: $o(1)$ is [Landau notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) for "quantity that converges to $0$:" so it will indeed disappear when taking the limit.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped a lot.